# how use toggle button in item custom listView?

Tags: android

I want to use a custom ListView  in my app..
I create a Myadapter the extends BaseAdapter.
Each item has a text view and toggle button..
The problem is that the program, when user clicked toggle button for item 1,
toggle button item 4 and item 6. Automatically switched...
I do not know what is the problem please help me...
Sorry. My English is not good

java code is:

```
 public class PayamActivity extends Activity  {



Myadapter adapter;
ListView list;
String [] payam;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);



    payam=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.payam);

     list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        }
public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater myInflater;
    public Myadapter(Context context) {
        myInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return payam.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder Holder;
        ;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            Holder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView=myInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_custom_layout,null );

            Holder.message=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_massege);

        Holder.heart=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton_heart);
            convertView.setTag(Holder);




        }
        else
            Holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



            Holder.message.setText(payam[position]);




        return convertView;
    }

}

public class ViewHolder extends Activity{
    TextView message;
    ToggleButton heart;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you clicking the toogle button , keep that row position in an arraylist or array whichever suitable for you...

And in `getview()`

add code like this,

```
if(array contains the id)
     Holder.heart.setchecked(true);
else
    Holder.heart.setchecked(false);
```

please check this link

http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/list-view-with-check-box-using-custom.html

Comment: thanks.. I have not array list in java code...i  do not know how I add the above code in my code?...

Comment: @anjeli hi please check the link that i posted

Comment: tanks sam...The above code works for checkbox.but i dont khow why dont work for toggle button..When I 'm scrolling toggle button Auto off!!!! I am cenfuse..thanks